# Cant install SQL Server 2012 Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, installation, ssms, windows-server-2012

I get up to the searching for product update and it just scans forever doesn't stop waited 2 hours and nothing so I skipped this step and go to next which is install setup files but it just says " not started " and the green bar just moves and moves and nothing happens no errors or anything

Comment: Did you ever found a solution?

Comment: @Prashant Gupta look at my answer, maybe it helps

Answer (score 7):

I just had a similar issue. Apparently this happens if there are problems with the wuauserv (windows update) service. Stopping this service made the endless update scan fail.

Comment: I did this as well as disabled my antivirus software during the installation process.

Answer (score 6):

I had the similar issue ..  install setup files and said " not started "  for almost 3 hrs.

Here is what I did and is now working fine.

1. Disabled the windows update service from task manager-> services .
2. Right clicked on setup file-> found that it was locked -> unlocked it.
3. Closed all the open installation window and started installing.
4. When prompted for installing and scanning updates, I skipped. It continued to further installation steps:-)

Comment: Right clicked on setup file-> found that it was locked -> unlocked it... what do you mean here? What kind of unlocking?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to restart the Windows Installer services.

Control Panel/Administrative Tools/Services/Windows Installer.

Comment: The service wasnt started, started it same issue restarted it and still the same thing

Comment: So, Right Click to setup exe file, go to Propierties and then UNLOCK the file and check the compatibility option. Open the file with Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue, what i did is I have downloaded new setup from Microsoft(I think new setup is not required but then also you can try). Then I have stop Window Update service. I have started Window Installer service from services.msc.

After Above changes run your Sql setup file. it will show update fail message, just click next and then it will take some time to and then it will allow to install.